# Return type deduction for methods of nested classes

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I encountered a problem relating to return type deduction for methods of nested classes. After some digging, I narrowed down the problem to a simplified version as following:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Alive {};

template<typename T>
auto is_alive_impl(...) -> void;

template<typename T>
auto is_alive_impl(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().operator()());

template<typename T>
struct is_alive : std::is_same<decltype(is_alive_impl<T>(0)), Alive> {};

struct Box {
    struct Cat {
        auto 
        operator()() {
            return Alive{};
        }
    };

    static constexpr auto value = is_alive<Cat>::value; // (1)
};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_alive<Box::Cat>::value); // (2)
}
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/zb9eoqe1K)

`struct is_alive` check if a class has `operator()` which return an `Alive` instance using function overloading trick.

Without line (1), the `static_assert` at (2) return `true` and the code compiles as expected.

However, I do not understand why adding line (1) make line (2) failed. It seems like I looked into the box and somehow killed the cat.

So here is my questions:

1. Why at line (1), `value` is false?
2. Why adding line (1) make line (2) failed?

It would be great if you can refer to parts of the Standard which dictate that behaviors.

Comment: Somehow changing `Cat::operator()`'s return type to `Alive` worked but don't know the reason though. My guess is `decltype(is_alive_impl<T>(0)` is not able to deduce `Alive` so they chose the other overload which returned `void`.

Comment: https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2335?

Comment: Line (1) makes (2) fail because different points of instantiation for a template must agree in terms of the ODR (that way, compilers can cache instantiations). When there is disagreement, the code is ill-formed; no diagnostic required. As for whether or not the disagreement itself is valid... above my pay grade.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So the compiler instantiate is_alive<Cat> at point (1) and cache the result to reuse at point (2)? But why at point (1), value is false? I thought the definition of class Cat is complete so value should be true? Thank you.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I tried the example in the issues (https://godbolt.org/z/GGc71Y7hs) and the compilers disagree with each others. So it is the phases of parse problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are running all your code more or less in SFINAE context and so you don't see any problem. If you simply try to instantiate your class by

```
int main() { Box::Cat bc; }
```

we see all the error messages.

What happens:

If you want inside the class define ( and not only declare! ) a variable which needs to deduce the return type of your `operator()` the statement fails as `auto` can not be deduced until the class is defined. ( by the end of the class definition with the close bracket. )
And this also lets fail the `std::declval<T>()` as the `auto value = is_alive<Cat>::value` will not work. And as we are in SFINAE context and the substitution silently fails, we run in the default template  `auto is_alive_impl(...) -> void;`. Bammm :-)

If we add a bit more indirection and put the cat in a smaller box, we can run the code:

```
struct LittleBox
{
    struct Cat {
        auto
        operator()()  {
            return Alive{};
        }
    };  

};

struct Box: public LittleBox {

    static constexpr  auto value = is_alive<Cat>::value; // (1)
};
```

OK, much simpler we can define the return type of the `operator()()` and don't use `auto` here.

The fix or work around seems to work on gcc/msvc/clang:[explore](https://godbolt.org/z/ozMb7j9xz)

Comment: When I do  `Box::Cat c;` it compiles fine. And with `Box b;` , in both cases the the objects are empty according to the debugger. Using the latest MSVC.

Comment: @lakeweb: Yep, also clang works but gcc fails. Seems to be hard at the edge of the standard. As "language lawyer" points to a defect report, we simply should treat that problem as a language defect :-) The fix or maybe work around seems to work on all platforms ( msvc/clang/gcc).

Comment: @Klaus Your `LittleBox` solution is interesting, It actually solve my problem. About the second suggestion (don't use auto) is not feasible in my particular case. Because I'm working with a template heavy library so writing down all the return type is not really practical. But one thing is not clear for me, why line (1) in my example return false? I thought class Cat definition is complete at that point of query?

Comment: @mibu I see both expressions return true or both return false. And as said I think it is because the object can not be instantiated during your SFINAE expression. And on which point the auto value can be deduced seems to be an open point of the standard and implementations handle it different. As we can not say what is right, we can't give the compiler vendors a bug report. That is the second time this week we find such language "features". Take it as it is. Sometimes language defect reports will stay for decades... :-)